# Cumulative distribution function of function of normal random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I have $X_1 \sim N(0, 4), X_2 \sim N(0, 4), X_3 \sim N(3, 1), X_4 \sim N(1, 9)$, they are independent. I need to find cumulative distribution function of $\xi = \frac{X_3X_2 + X_4X_1}{ \sqrt{X_4^2 + X_3^2}} $. Can you give me any clues? Thanks.